# API error returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric

Tags: ios, xcode

I got bellow API error :

```
<_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x155eac820; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x1c003a6c0>> returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
```

I have seen a lot of post related to this but did not find any solution?

Comment: i think you are trying to add text of uiTextField. Something like txtSome.text but you have missed .text. please check

Comment: can you please add some code?

Comment: I face to the very same error at UITextField, when isSecureTextEntry = true